# Вытащить подстроки регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, парсер

Есть строка вида
"Command -argument1(param1, param2) -argument2(param3)"

Аргументы и параметры могут содержать любые символы (кроме конца строки, естественно).  Надо с помощью регулярного выражения вытащить

"argument1(param1, param2)" 
и
"argument2(param3)"

Помогите составить правильное регулярное выражение, весь мозг поломал уже.

Comment: Как [вариант](https://regex101.com/r/bCP7LC/2) - `(?<=-)[^-]+(?=\s|$)`

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Еще бы добавить возможность, чтобы проглатывало строки с пробелами (разным количеством) между дефисом и аргументом при этом сами пробелы не учитывались. Т.е. из строки "-   argument(x)" выдирался "argument(x)"

Comment: `(?<=-)\s?([^-]+)(?=\s|$)` или даже так  `(?<=-)\s*([^-]+)(?=\s|$)`